# Matlab - How to compare values in a cell array?

Tags: arrays, cell

I have a set of inputs and one output declared in a cell array like that:

```
A = {'a', 'f', 'c', 'b';
     'b', 'f', 'c', 'a';
     'a', 'f', 'b', 'c';
     'c', 'f', 'b', 'a';
     'c', 'f', 'a', 'b';
     'b', 'f', 'a', 'c' }
```

where the first column is an output, and the rest are the inputs used, for each output.

I need to compare the values to reduce the calculation time.
So, the thing is, for equals outputs, I wanna know if the inputs are the same, a important remark.. the order of values desn't metter, so, when comparing f c b with f b c it is the same.

I need this because, acttualy, my data set is a 5040 x 7 cell array and I need to put them into a intorpolation function.

I thought in something like

if the value of the output column is equal to the another value of the same column, check if the value of inputs are all the same, using, ismember function. 
But I can not arrive to a code that works.

Any help, please?

Comment: What result do you want to achieve? Do you want to remove all of the duplicate input/output pairs, or do you just want a list telling you where the duplicates are?

Comment: I wanted to do exactly what you did, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you don't care about the order of the inputs, I would sort each of the rows:

```
[T, N] = size(A);
for t = 1:T
  Asorted(t,1)   = A(t,1);
  Asorted(t,2:N) = sort(A(t,2:N));
end
```

Now you want to find all of the duplicate rows. A simple way to do this is first to convert to a character array, and use the `unique` function --

```
B = cell2mat(Asorted);
[C, ii, jj] = unique(B,'rows');
```

Now `C` contains the unique rows of `B`, `ii` contains the indexes of the unique rows, and `jj` labels each of the rows of `B` depending on which unique value it has.

If you wanted to filter out all of the duplicate rows from `A`, you can now do

```
Afiltered = A(ii, :);
```

This results in:

```
Afiltered = 
    'a'    'f'    'b'    'c'
    'b'    'f'    'a'    'c'
    'c'    'f'    'a'    'b'
```